# Is there a way in process builder to check if a date is set and if so, if it is greater than something?

Tags: process-builder, date, comparable

I am trying to implement some form of attribution, where there are two cases:

1. Date has not been set (i.e. this is the first opportunity)
2. Date has been set (i.e. this is not the first opportunity)

Now I want to build the condition in the process builder in such a way that it works if 1 is met (i.e. date is empty), but also that it works if two (i.e. date is not empty) is met.

I used a custom logic alá (1 OR 2) and was hoping that if one evaluated to TRUE it would not check 2, but apparently that is not the case and the flow bugs out. Does anybody have an idea how to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

If both conditions are related to same field, then there is no sence to add them at all as any Opportunity will fit the "1 OR 2" criteria. You can use "No criteria—just execute the actions!" option instead:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let me know what the actions you need to check on both conditions.

is there any action you are going to take if your date is empty, or you just mentioned to avoid flow bug.

if only in second case you want your actions will run then you can use the condition like this:

[image]